# Microsoft Script Control - Expected "Then"

Tags: vbscript, controls

I've been developing some software to help organize my files better. To do this I have developed a script generator using Microsoft Script Control that then runs on files in a directory and returns a boolean value depending on whether they match the filter conditions.

Problem is, whenever I add any logical operators to the if statement, I get a COM exception because the code failed to compile, expecting "Then". I can't find a line number but I'm guessing it's something wrong with the If statement.

Here's an example which does compile:

```vb
Function FilterFiles(Name, Extension, Size, Directory, Created, Accessed, Modified)
Dim Result
If StrComp(Extension, ".jpg", 1) = 0 Then
Result = True
Else
Result = False
End If
FilterFiles = Result
End Function
```

And an example which doesn't:

```vb
Function FilterFiles(Name, Extension, Size, Directory, Created, Accessed, Modified)
Dim Result
If StrComp(Extension, ".jpg", 1) = 0 0r StrComp(Extension, ".png", 1) = 0 0r StrComp(Extension, ".psd", 1) = 0 Then
Result = True
Else
Result = False
End If
FilterFiles = Result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
.. 0 0r ..
```

instead of

```
.. 0 Or ..
```

looks like you use 0 (zero) instead of O (capital letter o) for the 0perator.

Comment: Thanks, that was a real howler on my part :-P

Comment: @Crazymoomin - you are welcome; don't feel bad - it happens to most of us non-robots.